# Background image/pattern

Tags: android, ios, background-image

I'm building an in-house "enterprise" app. Currently the design is pretty vanilla, and I'd like to spice it up a bit. I was thinking about adding an subtle image or pattern to the background. I found a nice pattern which consist of our company logo but it needed some editing. I contacted someone at our Marketing and Communication division and she told me if I gave her some specifications regarding size she could ask a 3rd-party company to make a tender.

The problem is, there are so many different screen-sizes with different resolutions nowadays, I find it really hard to provide a specification for the image.

1-size image: looks nicely on the resolution it's designed for, but looks stretched or compressed on different resolutions.

Pattern: normally can be repeated just fine, but with a company logo, the logo will probably become either stretched (low res) or very tiny with dozens across the height and width of the screen (high res).

There are many options for patterns, but it seemed nice to use our company logo, but as I described it causes some problems. The company that would be designing this company logo pattern is charging €100,- an hour, so I have to be sure it is exactly what we want to use.

Should I go with a background pattern containing our company logo at all? Should I just use a stock image to fill up the space?

Answer (score 0):

You should place the image in all drawable folders. Android will get image according to the screen resolution basis on the screen size. And you should provide images with required resolution. Because if you stretch a smaller image to be large it will definitelty effect the image quality.